# Is it legal to teach a subject you dont have a degree in?

Tags: education

I'm quite confused as to how my computer science class even exists right now. Mainly because the teacher knows just as little about coding in python as the students do. My teacher has admitted to getting most of his subject matter from youtube videos and from sites like StackOverflow.

He used to teach physics but the administration needed a computer science teacher so when they asked my teacher, it's quite apparent that he lied, said he could code (if he could code it was probably in a different coding language), and subsequently got the job. I'm currently a sophomore in high school (in Texas) if that helps to solve anything.

My main question is if there's something wrong here. Should he be allowed to teach this subject that he knows so little about? If so, should I take any actions in order to get a teacher that actually knows what they're doing?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @RonBeyer in the default one, of course.

Comment: There **is no default country** on Stack Exchange. @Greendrake

Comment: The default country is Uganda, isn't it?

Comment: @Nij I will accept that there is no default country once specifying country is made mandatory on asking questions here. But for now there is _de-facto_ default country: OPs from that country way more often feel no need to specify where they are from than OPs from any other country, and they are understood just fine. This question and answer is a perfect example.

Comment: Except they're not understood as being from any country in particular, even amongst those most commonly asked about. The laws of India, UK, USA and Australia are very different despite their common origins. Arrogantly assuming something to be true based in it being true, doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Greendrake You are talking about Uganda, right? If these people from Uganda refuse to specify a country, then they can't complain if they don't get useful answers.

Comment: @Nij "The laws of the USA" probably don't apply here, assuming the OP is from the US (I've noticed that people who don't think it's worthwhile mentioning a country are often from the US).  The laws of Texas or California or New Hampshire or wherever this is are much more likely to cover this.  If the OP could specify country and (in the US) state, that would help.

Comment: Laws of the USA include those from federal down to city, just as those of Australia and Germany do. Whichever laws happen to apply, the location is necessary to know which ones.

Comment: In the USA, Texas to be specific. Sorry, all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, your recourse is the school board that governs your high school. Talk to them and find out how to bring the situation to their attention. There will be some sort of complaint or grievance process you can participate in. The school board is bound by state (and federal law), but makes many decisions for the school, among them employee policies and standards for teacher qualifications. Yes, there are possible legal actions you could take, but the first step is the school board.

The school board will be obligated to tell you the hiring process and how qualifications play a role. But be aware that they have the option to hire temporary teachers who are not fully certified in order to fill vacancies; it's a common practice when the demand for teachers is much higher than their availability. There is little that is illegal about it, unless the board broke their own rules or state or federal law.